# html select + Font Awesome Icons = not working in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, select, icons

Font Awesome Icons in a html form select, are working in Chrome, Edge and Safari browsers, but not Firefox.

But if I set the select box to "multiple", then the icons displays...!

How to fix this?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'arial';
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>

Single select<br>
<select>
   <option>&#xf000</option>
   <option>&#xf001</option>
   <option>&#xf003</option>
   <option>&#xf004</option>
   <option>&#xf005</option>
</select>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d3cebjh2/15/)

Comment: This may help you [Open the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743167/5033493)

Comment: I've been around that question as well. And even Nagibabas solution won't show up in Firefox...