# How to use correctly fontawesome in select

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to show the fontawesome icons in a select, but in the drop-down list the icons are not previewed well

```css
.FontAwesomeSelect {
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select name="sample" id="sample" class="FontAwesomeSelect">
  <option value="">----</option>
  <option value="fa fa-address-card">&#xf2bb;</option>
  <option value="fa fa-bell">&#xf0f3;</option>
  <option value="fa fa-bookmark">&#xf02e;</option>
  <option value="fa fa-building">&#xf1ad;</option>
</select>
```

[image: Result:]

Comment: did you notice that it's working here ?

Comment: I have tried and working in Edge but not working in Chrome

Comment: You would have to build a custom control using JavaScript that includes an icon to mimic a select control

Comment: no it's working fine with chrome for me

Comment: very strange, I have tried on 3 devices without success,  will it be some kind of encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [font awesome icon in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `FontAwesomeSelect` class. Instead, use the default `fa` class.

```
<select name="sample" id="sample" class="fa">
        <option value="">----</option>
        <option value="fa fa-address-card">&#xf2bb;</option>
        <option value="fa fa-bell">&#xf0f3;</option>
        <option value="fa fa-bookmark">&#xf02e;</option>
        <option value="fa fa-building">&#xf1ad;</option>
</select>
```

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanParentLevesque/uwe8azo7/4/

[image: Demo font-awesome 5 in a drop down list]

Notice well what contains this class:

[image: Font-awesome CSS from Google Chrome console]

If it's still not working, try this:

```
.fa option {

    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: @Cris There are some known issues with IOS and OSX. You might want to check existing issues and create a new ticket if none solves your problem. https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues

Answer (score 0):

using the previous example i did this

```
<select name="sample" id="sample" class="fa">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="fa fa-address-card">&#xf2bb;</option>
    <option value="fa fa-bell">&#xf0f3;</option>
    <option value="fa fa-bookmark">&#xf02e;</option>
    <option value="fa fa-building">&#xf1ad;</option>
```

And add this custom css

```
select.form-control.fa option{ font-weight: 900; }
```

working with font awesome 5.6.3

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
    .fa option {
    font-weight: 900;
    }
</style>
```

Then the options can look like this:

```
<option class="fa" value="select_value">&#xf0f3; Name Of Select</option>
```