# How to place a font-awesome icon into a select drop-down menu?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have struggling to set a font-awesome icon in the select drop-down menu in vuejs. I have tried some ways like

```
<option selected value="fa fa-github"><i class="fab fa-github"> 
</i>Github</option>
```

But it didn't work. please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This is not related to  node.js or vue.js. This is a css, html and js question, for you need to use a library or use cutom stylings and js for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [font awesome icon in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put an `<i>` tag inside an `<select>` you can use the unicode directly inside the select and set the font with css.

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option selected value="fa fa-github">Github &#xf09b;</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Brands' , 'arial'
}
```

Example on this jsfiddle(font awesome 5):
https://jsfiddle.net/68avuypL/

Comment: Thanks, dude it works, one more question Is there any possibility to load my local image rather than using Font Awesome icon??

Comment: Not easily and probably requires some js but there is a question already about that on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list