# Font awesome Unicode icon is not shown in dropdown list

Tags: html, font-awesome

I have a dropdown to choose Male or Female. I want to show male or female icon beside the each option. I would like to use font awesome 5. To show icon I have used the Unicode of male and female icon from font awesome site. But the unicode is not showing. I have taken help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503416/how-to-place-a-font-awesome-icon-into-a-select-drop-down-menu)

**HTML Code:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
     <option value="" selected>Select Gender</option>
     <option value="">Male &#xf183;</option>
     <option value="">Female &#xf182;</option>
</select>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
select {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Brands' , 'arial'
  }
```

I have already added the font awesome [CSS CDN.](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css)

It works for github icon but does not works for Male or Female icon.

Comment: Can you add a snippet in the question?

Comment: That backslash over there, is that on purpose?

Comment: I don't know. I copied that from the attached link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem before, trying to add-in class in each option the corresponding class of icon

```
<select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
     <option value="" selected>Select Gender</option>
     <option class="fas fa-male"   value="male">Male &#xf183;</option>
     <option class="fas fa-female" value="female">Female &#xf182;</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you add cdn in your code ?
try this code.

```css
select {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Brands' , 'arial'
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">



<select>
<option selected value="fa fa-github">Github &#xf09b;</option>
</select>
<i class="fab fa-github"> </i>
```

Comment: I have already added the CSS link in my page. <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css'>

Comment: It's working for github icon but does not working for Male and Female icon