# How to put FontAwesome in the value of the select tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been searching how the FontAwesome can be implemented in the html files, though I have failed to come up with a result I want. Down below in the code, in the select tag I have tried some codes, except these I tried also with class instead of value.

I changed the js code too accordingly, and it failed to print what I wanted (it was printing the names and not the class [apparently I couldn't modify the code in a right way]). Usually, instead of having an icon, I end up having the text f the value i.e.'fa-windows' etc.

How can I handle the situation of the code. Below there is a picture, of what I want to achieve.

[image: What I want]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(
    "select option[value=" + $("select option:selected").val() + "]"
  ).css({
    "background-color": "#0000ff",
    color: "#fff"
  });
  $("select").change(function() {
    $("select option")[0].value = $("select option:selected").val();
    $("select option")[0].innerHTML = $("select option:selected").val();
    $("select").val($("select option:selected").val());
    $("select option").css({
      "background-color": "",
      color: ""
    });
    $(
      "select option[value=" + $("select option:selected").val() + "]"
    ).css({
      "background-color": "#0000ff",
      color: "#fff"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', serif;
}

.capsul {
  position: relative;
  top: 420px;
  left: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.operator {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ef8354;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -83px;
  left: 102px;
  border: none;
}

.download-link {
  position: relative;
  top: -58px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ef8354;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-left: 13px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/downloadbutton.css' %}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static " functionality/downloadbutton.js "%}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class=capsul>
    <a class="download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    <div>
      <label>
            <select class="operator">
              <option name="One" value="<i class='fa-windows'></i>">One</option>
              <option name="Two" value="2">Two</option>
              <option name="Three" value="3">Three</option>
              <option name="Four" value="fa fa-windows icon-default">Four</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743356/1377002

Comment: @Andy, thank you Andy, but that is not what i am after. In my code, in the select tag it shows the name, though when selected it shows only the value. Hence the link you gave me above, does not respond to my request. Thank you again

Comment: Why do you want the *value* of the option to be an icon?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, normally with some icons it works, i.e. $spades, though with the FontAwesome it fails. If not value, can it be done with any other attribute?!

Comment: Well, you didn't answer my question, to be fair. But can't you just use the unicode value as per what Andy linked?

Comment: Well, i am struggling to understand your question tbh! Plus i have mentioned above, that the link Andy gave, is not what i am looking for.

Comment: My question is: why do you need an icon as `value` instead of the icon being the displayed content of the `option`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Because, i am trying to build a download icon, so when i click the windows option i want only the windows logo to appear, and not the text 'windows, or icon together with the text.

Comment: Then you want it as `<option>DOWNLOAD_ICON</option>`, not `<option value="DOWNLOAD_ICON">...</option>`. (where `DOWNLOAD_ICON` would be the icon, once we understand how to show it). The former lets you *see* the icon, the latter doesn't. Or am I still not understanding?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'll try your suggestion, btw, i uploaded a picture, you can see above.

Comment: @umerselmani if you want to achieve that result, you're probably better off not using a select at all, IMHO. That looks like a floating `div` that appears when you click on the button.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, Alright man, thank you.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, hey dude, hope you are doing fine. I wanted to ask, what if i link a option value to an i or span tag. I will use the i/span tag to show the FontAwesome, and the select tag to select the options, hence, when i select an option from the dropdown, it will show the i tag corresponding to that select value.

Comment: @umerselmani if I understood you correctly, that's what the `select2` jquery-ui plugin does: put an invisible `select`, put some `div`s and when you click the `div`s it triggers the `onchange` for the invisible `select`. If that's what you had in mind, that's a viable strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function styleselect() {
  var value = $('#globalstyleselect').val();
  var div = $("#stylediv");
  if (value == "3") {
    div.html('<i class="fa-linux"></i>');
  }
  if (value == "2") {
    div.html('<i class="fa-apple"></i>');
  }
  if (value == "1") {
    div.html('<i class="fa-windows">');
  }
}
```

```css
i{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/downloadbutton.css' %}">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="{% static "functionality/downloadbutton.js"%}"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class=capsul>
      <div  >
        <label>
            <select id="globalstyleselect" onchange="styleselect()">
              <option value="1">Terra</option>
              <option value="2">Bella </option>
              <option value="3">Boca</option>
            </select>

            <span id="stylediv"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, Hey dude i found a solution. Again thank you for everything.

Comment: Good for you :) Happy I could help