# CSS custom dropdown menu with text and coloured square

Tags: html, css

I'd like to include a coloured square next to each item in my dropdown menu. It should look like the 'Description' column here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color

I tried this method: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_shapes_square, but didn't get anywhere.

Thank you!

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
    a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    x[i].appendChild(a);
    /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
    b = document.createElement("DIV");
    b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
    for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
        /* For each option in the original select element,
        create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
        c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
            and the selected item: */
            var y, i, k, s, h;
            s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
            for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                    s.selectedIndex = i;
                    h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                    y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                    for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                        y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                    }
                    this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                    break;
                }
            }
            h.click();
        });
        b.appendChild(c);
    }
    x[i].appendChild(b);
    a.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
        and open/close the current select box: */
        e.stopPropagation();
        closeAllSelect(this);
        this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
        this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
    /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
    except the current select box: */
    var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
    y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt == y[i]) {
            arrNo.push(i)
        } else {
            y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
            x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
        }
    }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
    /* The container must be positioned relative: */
    .custom-select {
        position: relative;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .custom-select select {
        display: none;
        /*hide original SELECT element: */
    }

    .select-selected {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    /* Style the arrow inside the select element: */
    .select-selected:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        top: 14px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 6px solid transparent;
        border-color: #717171 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    /* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */
    .select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
        border-color: transparent transparent #717171 transparent;
        top: 7px;
    }

    /* style the header: */
    .select-selected {
        color: #494848;
        font-size: 13px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* style the items (options): */
    .select-items {
        color: #494848;
        font-size: 13px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 10px 16px;
        line-height: 1.6;
        border: 0.5px solid transparent;
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Style items (options): */
    .select-items {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: White;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    /* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */
    .select-hide {
        display: none;
    }

    .select-items div:hover,
    .same-as-selected {
        background-color: rgba(246, 245, 245, 0.9);
    }

    /* Style the submit button: */
    .myButton {
        background-color: #286BEF;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: 550;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 12px 23px;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 280px;
    }

    .myButton:hover {
        background-color: #0688fa;
    }

    .myButton:relative {
        top: 10px;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    /*Style event names: */
    p {
        color: #494848;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <p>Notes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
            <select>
                <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
                <option value="RED">Red</option>
                <option value="GREEN">Green</option>
                <option value="BLUE">Blue</option>
                <option value="ORANGE">Orange</option>
                <option value="YELLOW">Yellow</option>
                <option value="MAUVE">Purple</option>
                <option value="PALE_GREEN">Pale green</option>
                <option value="PALE_RED">Pale red</option>
                <option value="PALE_BLUE">Pale blue</option>
                <option value="CYAN">Cyan</option>
                <option value="GRAY">Grey</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" class="myButton">Submit</a>
```

Comment: You've just got an styled select, but I don't see where you tried to add the squares, no CSS and no Javascript for them.

Comment: In CSS I tried '.select-items.square {
  height: 2px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #555;
}' and in html I tried to include the square into the dropdown menu like this: '<option value="ORANGE"><div class="square"></div>Orange</option>'. I copied and pasted the entire Javascript bit from W3 Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp) and I'm absolutely not proficient enough in Javascript to read this script so I haven't made any changes to it.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option

Comment: Hi @Cooper, that's actually very helpful, thanks! I think I'm almost there, but my icon doesn't show up correctly. Is that because I'm using Arial for the rest of the text or what might it be? https://codepen.io/Omega3/pen/LYEjOox. This is the icon I'd like to use: https://fontawesome.com/icons/square-full?style=solid

Comment: I played with the example at your link by loading it into another example of mine and I had to mess around with the positioning a lot to find it.  I found it useful to go into Chrome developer tool elements and modify the element.style to  get it located properly.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What positioning are you referring to? And how does it affect the icon? element.style looks empty when I inspect it in Chrome, but I'm also new to any sort of front-end development so apologies if these questions are rather basic.

Comment: Actually, I've just been trying to work with a select drop down and I couldn't get anything to work.  I have  feeling that HtmlService is removing it because I can't even see the html  in Chrome developers tools.  At this point I think I'd just go with changing the color of the option backgrounds.

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I thought of a different approach. I used &#9679; as shape, which leaves me with implementing the colour. It works fine for a simple example such as this one: https://codepen.io/Omega3/pen/abzyxNm, but I can't replicate it in my code. I think it may not pick up option and class because they've been assigned different names in JS? https://codepen.io/Omega3/pen/LYEjOox

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
.select-items > div:nth-child(1)::first-letter {
         color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply assign the text, or value, of the `<option>` elements as a CSS custom property of the `<div>` elements you're creating, and then take advantage of CSS generated content to create the colour swatch, for example:

```
// here we use CSS.setProperty to set the property-value of
// the --colour custom property to the value contained within
// the <option> element over which we're iterating:
c.style.setProperty('--colour', selElmnt.options[j].value);
```

And, in the CSS:

```
/* we style the <div> elements using CSS Grid,
   although flex would work perfectly well */
.select-items > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "colour colourName";
  grid-template-columns: 1em max-content;
/* here we set a gap between 'swatch' and the
   text-content: */
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
/* setting padding to enforce spacing between
   elements above and below: */
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
/* creating the pseudo-elements: */
.select-items > div::before {
  content: '';
/* here we set the background-color of the current
   pseudo-element to the value held in the --colour
   custom property: */
  background-color: var(--colour);
/* and place the pseudo-element in the named
   grid-area: */
  grid-area: colour;
}
```

The notable caveat with this approach, though, is that the property-value held in the `<option>` element's `value` attribute must be a valid CSS value, as the following demonstration illustrates (note the lack of a colour swatch for both the colours prefixed with 'pale' and the 'purple' colour, which for some reason has the value of 'mauve'):

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.style.setProperty('--colour', selElmnt.options[j].value);
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var y, i, k, s, h;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #717171 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #717171 transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
.select-selected {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  border: 0.5px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: White;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.select-items>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "colour colourName";
  grid-template-columns: 1em max-content;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
.select-items>div::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--colour);
  grid-area: colour;
}
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(246, 245, 245, 0.9);
}
.myButton {
  background-color: #286BEF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 12px 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #0688fa;
}
.myButton:relative {
  top: 10px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
p {
  color: #494848;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Notes</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
      <select>
        <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
        <option value="RED">Red</option>
        <option value="GREEN">Green</option>
        <option value="BLUE">Blue</option>
        <option value="ORANGE">Orange</option>
        <option value="YELLOW">Yellow</option>
        <option value="MAUVE">Purple</option>
        <option value="PALE_GREEN">Pale green</option>
        <option value="PALE_RED">Pale red</option>
        <option value="PALE_BLUE">Pale blue</option>
        <option value="CYAN">Cyan</option>
        <option value="GRAY">Grey</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" class="myButton">Submit</a>
```

To rectify that, the easiest solution would be to modify those values in some way, either using different – recognised HTML – colour-names in the `value` attribute, or using some other colour notation, such as `rgb()`/`rgba()`, `hsl()`/`hsla()` or hexadecimal.

Using updated HTML colour names, for example:

```
<select>
  <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
  <option value="RED">Red</option>
  <option value="GREEN">Green</option>
  <option value="BLUE">Blue</option>
  <option value="ORANGE">Orange</option>
  <option value="YELLOW">Yellow</option>
  <option value="PURPLE">Purple</option>
  <option value="PALEGREEN">Pale green</option>
  <option value="LIGHTCORAL">Pale red</option>
  <option value="PALETURQUOISE">Pale blue</option>
  <option value="CYAN">Cyan</option>
  <option value="GRAY">Grey</option>
</select>
```

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.style.setProperty('--colour', selElmnt.options[j].value);
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var y, i, k, s, h;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #717171 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #717171 transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
.select-selected {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  border: 0.5px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: White;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.select-items>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "colour colourName";
  grid-template-columns: 1em max-content;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
.select-items>div::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--colour);
  grid-area: colour;
}
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(246, 245, 245, 0.9);
}
.myButton {
  background-color: #286BEF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 12px 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #0688fa;
}
.myButton:relative {
  top: 10px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
p {
  color: #494848;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Notes</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
      <select>
        <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
        <option value="RED">Red</option>
        <option value="GREEN">Green</option>
        <option value="BLUE">Blue</option>
        <option value="ORANGE">Orange</option>
        <option value="YELLOW">Yellow</option>
        <option value="PURPLE">Purple</option>
        <option value="PALEGREEN">Pale green</option>
        <option value="LIGHTCORAL">Pale red</option>
        <option value="PALETURQUOISE">Pale blue</option>
        <option value="CYAN">Cyan</option>
        <option value="GRAY">Grey</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" class="myButton">Submit</a>
```

Updated hex values:

```
<select>
  <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
  <option value="#f00">Red</option>
  <option value="#0f0">Green</option>
  <option value="#00f">Blue</option>
  <option value="#fa0">Orange</option>
  <option value="#ff0">Yellow</option>
  <option value="#808">Purple</option>
  <option value="#90fb98">Pale green</option>
  <option value="#f08080">Pale red</option>
  <option value="#aee">Pale blue</option>
  <option value="#0ff">Cyan</option>
  <option value="#808080">Grey</option>
</select>
```

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.style.setProperty('--colour', selElmnt.options[j].value);
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var y, i, k, s, h;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #717171 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #717171 transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
.select-selected {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
   .select-items {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  border: 0.5px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: White;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.select-items>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "colour colourName";
  grid-template-columns: 1em max-content;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
.select-items>div::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--colour);
  grid-area: colour;
}
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(246, 245, 245, 0.9);
}
.myButton {
  background-color: #286BEF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 12px 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #0688fa;
}
.myButton:relative {
  top: 10px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
p {
  color: #494848;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Notes</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
      <select>
        <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
        <option value="#f00">Red</option>
        <option value="#0f0">Green</option>
        <option value="#00f">Blue</option>
        <option value="#fa0">Orange</option>
        <option value="#ff0">Yellow</option>
        <option value="#808">Purple</option>
        <option value="#90fb98">Pale green</option>
        <option value="#f08080">Pale red</option>
        <option value="#aee">Pale blue</option>
        <option value="#0ff">Cyan</option>
        <option value="#808080">Grey</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" class="myButton">Submit</a>
```

Obviously modifying the `value` attribute risks adverse effects on what you're doing with those values – inserting into a database or integrating with another API for example – so, rather than updating the `value` attribute it may be preferred to introduce a custom `data-*` attribute to hold the representation of the desired colour:

```
<select>
  <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
  <option value="RED" data-swatch="red">Red</option>
  <option value="GREEN" data-swatch="green">Green</option>
  <option value="BLUE" data-swatch="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="ORANGE" data-swatch="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="YELLOW" data-swatch="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="MAUVE" data-swatch="purple">Purple</option>
  <option value="PALE_GREEN" data-swatch="palegreen">Pale green</option>
  <option value="PALE_RED" data-swatch="lightcoral">Pale red</option>
  <option value="PALE_BLUE" data-swatch="paleturquoise">Pale blue</option>
  <option value="CYAN" data-swatch="cyan">Cyan</option>
  <option value="GRAY" data-swatch="grey">Grey</option>
</select>
```

With the slightly modified JavaScript, to use the `HTMLElement.dataset` API to retrieve the value held in the custom `data-swatch` attribute:

```
c.style.setProperty('--colour', selElmnt.options[j].dataset.swatch);
```

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.style.setProperty('--colour', selElmnt.options[j].dataset.swatch);
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var y, i, k, s, h;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #717171 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #717171 transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
.select-selected {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
  color: #494848;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  border: 0.5px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: White;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.select-items>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "colour colourName";
  grid-template-columns: 1em max-content;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
.select-items>div::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--colour);
  grid-area: colour;
}
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(246, 245, 245, 0.9);
}
.myButton {
  background-color: #286BEF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 12px 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #0688fa;
}
.myButton:relative {
  top: 10px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
p {
  color: #494848;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Notes</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
      <select>
        <option value="Please select a colour">Please select a colour</option>
        <option value="RED" data-swatch="red">Red</option>
        <option value="GREEN" data-swatch="green">Green</option>
        <option value="BLUE" data-swatch="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="ORANGE" data-swatch="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="YELLOW" data-swatch="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="MAUVE" data-swatch="purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="PALE_GREEN" data-swatch="palegreen">Pale green</option>
        <option value="PALE_RED" data-swatch="lightcoral">Pale red</option>
        <option value="PALE_BLUE" data-swatch="paleturquoise">Pale blue</option>
        <option value="CYAN" data-swatch="cyan">Cyan</option>
        <option value="GRAY" data-swatch="grey">Grey</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" class="myButton">Submit</a>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- JavaScript:

  - [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).

Bibliography:

- "[Web Colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)," Wikipedia.