# JavaScript: error rendering icons from Icons - Material Design

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to override the values of some option fields so instead of render numbers, render stars. I'm using vanilla JavaScript and Material-icons (only the icons)

**script.js**

```
var select_field = document.getElementsByClassName('select_input')

for (const iterator of select_field) {
    var options_list = iterator.options;

    options_list[1].innerHTML = "<span class='material-icons'>star</span>"
...
}
```

This is the code when I inspect the code:

```
<option value="1"> <span class='material-icons'>star</span> </option>
```

But the output is:

```
star
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743356/863110) can help you

Comment: You can't put HTML inside `<option>`. It just doesn't work that way.