# Add Icons next to text in dropmenu

Tags: html

I just want to know the right way to add a flag icon next to text in a dropmenu using  and

```
   <select name="to">
<option value="cnd">Canadian <img src="usaflag.png" alt="usa-flag" width="12" height="12"> </option>
<option value="usa">American</option>
<option value="ero">Euro</option>
<option value="brp">British Pound</option>
<option value="chy">Chinese Yuan</option>
</select>
```

that's what i tried but it doesn't work. What's the right way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [font awesome icon in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option)