# Icons in Html Select Options

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-awesome

ill try a lot now but i can't solve it.
ill try it the way like it is described here:  [font awesome icon in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option)

i want to put some font awesome icons in my select for some options i know u cant put an  in the options but i read there is a possibilty to use the unicode:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/sort-up this is one of the icons i want to use with the unicode : f0de and i insert it like this with no effect what am i missing ?

```
<div class="sort_filter_container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form name="view_type_sorting" class="form-group" action="" method="get">
                    <span><b>[{oxmultilang ident="SORT_VIEW"}]: </b></span>
                    <select style="text-align-last: center;font-weight: 600;margin-right: 0;vertical-align: text-bottom;" id="view_type_sorting" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="view_type_sorting">
                        <option id="list_asc_price" name="list_asc_price" value="list_asc_price">[{oxmultilang ident="PRICE_UP"}] &#xf09b;</option>
                        <option id="list_desc_price" name="list_desc_price" value="list_desc_price">[{oxmultilang ident="PRICE_DOWN"}]</option>
                        <option id="list_asc_alpha" name="list_asc_alpha" value="list_asc_alpha">[{oxmultilang ident="NAME_UP"}]</option>
                        <option id="list_desc_alpha" name="list_desc_alpha" value="list_desc_alpha">[{oxmultilang ident="NAME_DOWN"}]</option>
                        <option id="list_default" name="list_default" value="list_default">[{oxmultilang ident="DEFAULT_GRID"}]</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use **[`Fontawesome version 4.7.0`](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp)**

Add font-family to `#view_type_sorting`

```
#view_type_sorting{
  font-family:"FontAwesome";
}
```

```css
#view_type_sorting{
  font-family:"FontAwesome";
  font-size:14px;
}
#view_type_sorting::before{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="sort_filter_container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form name="view_type_sorting" class="form-group">
            <select style="text-align-last: center;font-weight: 600;margin-right: 0;vertical-align: text-bottom;" id="view_type_sorting" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="view_type_sorting">
                <option id="list_asc_price" name="list_asc_price" value="list_asc_price"> Github &#xf09b; </option>
                <option id="list_desc_price" name="list_desc_price" value="list_desc_price"> GitLab &#xf296; </option>
                <option id="list_asc_alpha" name="list_asc_alpha" value="list_asc_alpha"> Whatsapp &#xf232;</option>
                <option id="list_desc_alpha" name="list_desc_alpha" value="list_desc_alpha"> Google Plus &#xf0d5; </option>
                <option id="list_default" name="list_default" value="list_default"> Facebook &#xf082; </option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to change the height of the icon too ?

Comment: Can you try to change font-size? instead of icon height.

Comment: nope, ill try to change the font-size in the id  #view_type_sorting now but i can't get it in the center, ill also try the vertical-align but no effect. Ill try to figure something out thanks

Comment: Are you want how much font-sze?

Comment: i have font-size 14px , ill try to get &#xf0de; in one line with the text

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/) and do something like this:

```html
<div class="font-awesome">
<label>Font Awesome</label>
<select class="fa">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option class="fa" selected>Hi i am &#xf2b9 fontawesome</option>
    <option class="fa">Hi i am &#xf30b fontawesome</option>
    <option class="fa">Hi i am &#xf0f3 fontawesome</option>
    <option class="fa">Hi i am &#xf273 fontawesome</option>
    <option class="fa">Hi i am &#xf080 fontawesome</option>
</select>
```

```css
.font-awesome .fa {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", Open Sans;
    font-weight: 501;
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/MuhammadOvi/pen/MWyVWgB)