# ASP.NET MVC - Populate SelectList with Font-Awesome Icons

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've populated List with font-awesome strings like:

```cs
private static readonly List<string> Icons = new(){
    "<i class=\"fas fa-users\"></i>",
    "<i class=\"fas fa-user-tag\"></i>",
    "<i class=\"fas fa-sitemap\"></i>",
    "<i class=\"fas fa-cubes\"></i>",
    "<i class=\"fas fa-shield-alt\"></i>"
};
```

And in View I have a dropdown:

```
<select asp-for="Icon" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Icons"></select>
```

and then when I display them in SelectList I get:

[image]

I would like to render them as HTML and display icons, not strings. Is it possible? Maybe with JS or jQuery?

Comment: i dont think its possible without hacks, afaik option elements dont support html inside of them, so you have to create a custom element which behaves like a select

Comment: Is it possible somehow with jQuery or just JS?

Comment: i assume its possible with both take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, [Tag Helper is for ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You may change your question tag to `.net-core`, `asp.net-core-mvc`, `asp.net-core` relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot render `<i>` icon element in `<option>` element as asked this question: [Font Awesome icon in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36743041/8017690).

Instead, you can pass the Unicode to the `<option>` element in order to show the icon.

**Step 1**: Get the icons' Unicode from [FontAwesome website](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2).

**Step 2**: Pass the icons' Unicode to `SelectList`.

> **Note 1**: The Unicode that passed to front-end must be in the format: `&#x{Unicode};`
>
> **Note 2**: You may remove `<i>` element string and redesign `Icons` type in case `<i>` element is not needed.

> Controller

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Icons = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "<i class=\"fas fa-users\"></i>", "&#xf0c0;" },
        { "<i class=\"fas fa-user-tag\"></i>", "&#xf507;" },
        { "<i class=\"fas fa-sitemap\"></i>", "&#xf0e8;" },
        { "<i class=\"fas fa-cubes\"></i>", "&#xf1b3;" },
        { "<i class=\"fas fa-shield-alt\"></i>", "&#xf3ed;" }
    };

    ViewBag.Icons = new SelectList((IEnumerable)Icons, "Key", "Value");
}
```

**Step 3**: Render `<option>` elements with `@Html.Raw(item.Text)` .

> Note: Unicode to be generated as `IHtmlString` instead of `string`.

> View

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all.min.css" />

    <style>

        select {
            font-family: 'FontAwesome', Verdana;
        }

        .fa option {
            font-weight: 900;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

```
<select asp-for="Icon" class="form-control fa">
    @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.Icons)
    {
        <option value="@item.Value">
            @Html.Raw(item.Text)
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

> Result

[image]