# How to add SVG icon to a select element

Tags: html, css

I have a a select element with a custom arrow like this:

```
  <div className="row">
    <select>
      <!-- options -->
    </select>
    <Icon />
  </div>
```

Currently only clicking the select element opens the dropdown. I get an error saying I can't put the Icon inside the select element, so what can I do to make clicking the icon also open the select element? Preferably without JS

Comment: What is `<Icon />`? You can have an icon in the options using unicode but overall I'm not entirely sure what your goal is.

Comment: @ChrisW. It's an SVG from FontAwesome. When I click on it, it should open the select menu, but it doesn't. I've seen some hypothetical JS solutions that don't actually work (e.g. calling `click` on the select element), but ideally, the icon would be inside the select element somehow so no JS hacks are needed.

Comment: Yea, that would be expected. Do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option) instead. You can find the unicode value for the icon on the corresponding icon's page on their website, though if it's a new version the `font-family` you'll need to specify will be like "FontAwesome 5 Free" instead of just "FontAwesome"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a custom arrow icon you can set a **background image** and `appearance: none;`.

If you need an external button to open your select – you'll need to change the `size` attribute via js.

```js
let select = document.querySelector("#select");
let options = select.querySelectorAll("option");

function openSelect() {
  if (!select.size) {
    select.size = options.length;
  } else {
    closeSelect();
  }
}

function closeSelect() {
  console.log("close");
  select.size = false;
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.select-wrp {
  width: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.select-wrp * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: inherit;
}


.select-custom-icon {
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='icon icon-prefix-chevron-down' id='icon-prefix-chevron-down' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpolyline points='6 9 12 15 18 9' fill='none' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-width='4' stroke='red' %3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrp">
  <select class="select-custom-icon">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="select-wrp">
  <button class="btnOpenSelect" onclick="openSelect()" onblur="closeSelect()">Open Select</button>
  <select onblur="closeSelect()" onclick="closeSelect()" id="select">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```