# Bind Icon in dropdown list in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a dropdown in Vue.Js, I need to Bind Font Awesome icon after each dropdown items.

I am new to Vue.js so please guide how to do that. I am using below code to bind items in dropdown

```html
<select id="testID" v-model="testModel" v-on:change="changeEvent">
  <option v-bind:value="da" v-for="da in data.Users">
    {{da.DisplayText}}
  </option>
<select>
```

What i have tried so Far

I tried to use  element inside option tag but did not get any thing. I tried below syntax also

```html
<select id="testID" v-model="testModel" v-on:change="changeEvent">
  <option v-bind:value="da" v-for="da in data.Users">
    {{da.DisplayText}}
    <span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
  </option>
<select>
```

I tried Image tag also but no luck so far. I am using `<i>` tag because i need to raise a javascript event on mouse over of each drop down item.
Please help

Comment: i just want to make sure, did you mean to give icon in every dropdown items?

Comment: Yes, But i need to raise an event also to show a pop up on hovvering on that icon.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're trying to handle this _event_ you keep mentioning

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the Unicode version of the icon instead.

For the circle icon the unicode value is `&#xf111;`

[Link](https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?s=solid) to icon.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select id="testID" v-model="testModel" v-on:change="changeEvent">
    <option v-bind:value="da" v-for="da in data.Users">{{da.DisplayText}} &#xf111;</option>
</select>
```

Check out this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option). Should answer your question.

Comment: I tried this but if i will use this then how i will raise the mouse over event on the icon itself. So Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: You cannot do that with the `<option>` element. Instead you are better off implementing a rendered list and doing the logic yourself using divs and lists.