# How to display box icon in select option tag

Tags: html, css, icons, box

Box-icon is displaying successfully outside .
But I can't display box-icons inside .

```
<select class="form-select form-control" aria-label="Select Icon" id="new_category_icon">
  <option value="1"><i class="bx bx-block"></i></option>
  <option value="2"><i class='bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2'></i></option>
  <option value="3"><i class='bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2'></i></option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Look at the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) - only `text` content is permitted

Comment: Is there no way to display <option> Icon & Text ?

Comment: Not with vanilla HTML. There might be other alternatives out there but you cannot even use the pseudo selectors (`:before/:after`) to apply styles. [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option)